# Checkout.com: Hosted payments, Is it possible to Reuse Card Details?

Tags: python, payment, credit-card, checkout-payments

https://api-reference.checkout.com/previous/#operation/createAHostedPaymentsSession

Hi. I am using checkout.com hosted-payments to create payments for my e-shop. I am reading through the docs and I am trying to understand if it's possible to reuse the card details and re-use them on the next hosted-payment creation in order to pre-fill the User's card details.

I don't want to save the card details. I just want a way to prefill them on the next payment

I know that behind the scenes when I do create a hosted-payment checkout creates a `customer` object and also when I get the payment later on after the checkout finish my `payment` object contains a `source` object that has a `fingerprint` and some other card information.

Unfortunately I do not see any option for this on the docs. Anyone has done this before and maybe know if this is even possible ?

I was expecting to have a source_id param on the hosted-payments endpoint that will pre-fill the card details

Comment: These APIs are designed so that you as the client of these payment platforms (acting on behalf of your customers) **do not** need to process any sensitive information, scrolling further down may have [brought you to this section](https://api-reference.checkout.com/previous/#tag/Tokens) where they provide tokens to represent your customer's payment details. As per [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002189/), **DON'T DO IT** (even then, following standards like PA DSS/PCI may be a legal requirement in your jurisdictions and breaches will become a legal liability).

Comment: @metatoaster Thank you for your answer. Indeed I don't wanna store the information that why I also changed the title to reuse. My problem is that I cannot find any option related to token or source when creating a hosted_payment here https://api-reference.checkout.com/previous/#operation/createAHostedPaymentsSession

Comment: Try searching for `previous_payment_id` in that page. Honestly it might be quicker for you to email the support email and their support team will likely give you an answer **much** quicker than here.